# add CD limits in the Friedman-Nemenyi test

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm a new user of the Python. I've already compared different machine learning regressions based on jupyter notebook, and I run the Friedman-Nemenyi test. I would be very appreciative if somebody looks at my code and advise me on how can I add CD limits in the Friedman-Nemenyi test.

```
# This method computes the critical difference for Nemenyi test
cd = compute_CD(average_ranks, n=len(df), alpha='0.05', test='nemenyi')
# This method generates the plot.
graph_ranks(average_ranks, names=algorithms_names, cd=2.8, width=10, textspace=1.5, reverse=False)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKKyJ.jpg)

My code for comparing different machine learning regressions works. But I have no idea how can I add CD limits in the Friedman-Nemenyi test. Finally, I would like to create the below figure 2. Apologies for my errors in the code and my explanation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nzzq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The `compute_CD` method is now deprecated in the latest Orange3 package, so I couldn't reproduce it. However, I found the [autorank](https://github.com/sherbold/autorank) package which is able to perform most of statistical tests.

To perform the Nemenyi post-hoc test, you need to have a dataframe of various models and its corresponding evaluation results (an excerpt from my personal project):

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 | Model 3 | Model 4 | Model 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Metric 1 | 0.01 | 0.02 | 0.03 | 0.04 | 0.05 |
| Metric 2 | 0.05 | 0.04 | 0.03 | 0.02 | 0.01 |
| Metric 3 | 0.04 | 0.02 | 0.01 | 0.05 | 0.03 |

Here, you can see that the evaluation results are in rows, and models in the columns.

Pass this dataframe to autorank and plot the critical distance plot:

```
from autorank import autorank, plot_stats

result = autorank(df, alpha=0.05, verbose=False, order='ascending')
plot_stats(result)
plt.show()
```

Notes:

1. Use `order='ascending'` if the metrics are error based (smaller the better)
2. Your dataframe format must be models in the columns and evaluation metrics in the rows.